# Are migrations in ruby on rails updates to a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is is correct to assume that migrations in ruby on rails are simply updates to any database. And that the rake db:migrate script only serves to actualize these changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

> Migrations are a convenient way for you to alter your database in a
>   structured and organized manner. You could edit fragments of SQL by
>   hand but you would then be responsible for telling other developers
>   that they need to go and run them. You’d also have to keep track of
>   which changes need to be run against the production machines next time
>   you deploy.
>
> Active Record tracks which migrations have already been run so all you
>   have to do is update your source and run rake db:migrate. Active
>   Record will work out which migrations should be run. It will also
>   update your db/schema.rb file to match the structure of your database.
>
> Migrations also allow you to describe these transformations using
>   Ruby. The great thing about this is that (like most of Active Record’s
>   functionality) it is database independent: you don’t need to worry
>   about the precise syntax of CREATE TABLE any more than you worry about
>   variations on SELECT * (you can drop down to raw SQL for database
>   specific features). For example you could use SQLite3 in development,
>   but MySQL in production.

Source: [Ruby on Rails Guides: Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)